# lake shore, sea coast, river side

Tags: vocabulário

What do you call these three things in Portuguese?

lake shore, sea coast, river side

Here are my suggestions:

lake shore = costa do lago

sea coast = costa do mar

river side = lado do rio

Am I right?

I prefer the Brazilian Portuguese.

Comment: It's nice if you give us some context.

Comment: cornejo, as @JorgeB. said, could you provide some sample sentences? It would make your question much better. :)

Comment: cornejo we need some context to prevent pointless discussions and to answer correctly to your questions.

Answer (score 4):

The following words are current usage in pt-BR

- "A frente fria deve atingir **a costa** do sudeste na manhã de segunda-feira."
- "A estrada de ferro corre junto **à margem** do rio Doce por 120 quilômetros."
- "A população que vive **à beira** do lago tira o seu sustento da pesca"

To say "costa do mar" would be redundant.

There are other words, mainly regional terms, but the above are used and understood from north to south in Brazil.

Examples from books:

> - "a bela Dara estava sentada [**à beira do lago**"](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=l1SuCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA9&dq=a+beira+do+lago&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiptMvdqc_QAhWFhZAKHbogAtkQ6AEIKTAC)
> - "Em Montreux, [**à beira do lago de Genebra**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=u61cu2PaC0kC&pg=PT11&dq=a+beira+do+lago&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiptMvdqc_QAhWFhZAKHbogAtkQ6AEIOTAF)
>     , chamou-nos a atenção uma senhora..."
> - "a multidão comprimia Jesus para ouvir a palavra de Deus; [**ele estava à beira do lago**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=HAX--ReEVucC&pg=PA95&dq=a+beira+do+lago&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9_LiJq8_QAhUBxpAKHe5mDU04ChDoAQhKMAY) de Genesaré"
> - " Como [**sua residência ficava à beira do lago**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=UfWnBAAAQBAJ&pg=RA1-PR39&dq=a+beira+do+lago&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiI_5vvq8_QAhVEFZAKHbONBAo4FBDoAQgoMAA), diante da ilhota..."
> - "Sua mãe já foi várias vezes [**até a beira do lago**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=xj3ewewbcMsC&pg=PT189&dq=a+beira+do+lago&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiI_5vvq8_QAhVEFZAKHbONBAo4FBDoAQgzMAI)..."

Comment: In Portugal too.

Comment: @JorgeB. For pt-PT, I disagree about "beira". I think that it does not mean "coast", it means "near". It could mean "edge", in other similar uses.

Comment: @ANeves   When an American says "I'm from the west coast", they don't mean they could see the sea from their homes.  When the weather man in Brazil says "a costa do nordeste vai receber um pouco de chuva neste final de semana", he doesn't mean only the stretch of sand in contact with the ocean.  True, "beira" means near, but "à beira do lago" is idiomatic in pt-BR.  Nobody says "a costa do lago"

Comment: I'm silly, and I should have mentioned "beira and shore" (and not "beira and coast"). Regardless: you are right, @Centaurus , in most of your comment; I only disagree with "à beira", which in that example I think means "in the vicinity of", such as: "A população que vive à beira da floresta tira o seu sustento da caça." But I'm not pt-BR, so... :)

Comment: The plural "às margens do ..." is sometimes used too.

Comment: @ANeves   "I only disagree with "à beira", which in that example..."   How would you say it in pt-PT

Comment: @bfavaretto    As margens plácidas do riacho Ipiranga certamente ouviram o brado retumbante de um povo heroico.

Comment: if we have some context this discussion doesn't exists.

Comment: I remove my disagreement. After re-reading these comments with a fresh head, together with the answer from @Jacinto and its... exposition of the broad meaning of "coast", now I notice that you mean the same for beira. I stand corrected! :) Thank you for being patient.

Comment: @Aneves e Centaurus, *à beira do lago* is perfectly idiomatic. But *beira do lago* would not be my first choice for an equivalent to *lakeshore* outside that phrase. I would say *as margens do lago estão poluídas* sooner than *a beira do lago está poluída*; *ocuparam as margens do lago* rather than *ocuparam a beira do lago*; *o lago é bonito; as suas margens são* rather than *a sua beira é*. I feel *à beira de* is more of an equivalent to *by*: *estou à beira do lago* = *I'm by the lake*; or *casa à beira do rio/da estrada*.

Comment: @Jacinto   Both nouns are current usage in pt-BR. To me, however, "à beira do lago" means anywhere from the point water meets sand or rock, to across the street or road, if there is any.  And it's the word I use.

Comment: What I mean is, say, how would you translate these bits about Lake Michigan [Wikipedia]( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Michigan): “Ports along its **shores** include Chicago […]” or “ferry services […] connecting Wisconsin on the western **shore** with Michigan on the east”?

Comment: @Jacinto   Lake Michigan is a huge body of water, comparable to a sea. Undoubtedly I would use "coast".

Comment: I rest my case :) I use *costa* for large lakes as well, but maybe not in these cases. *Costa* is usually used from a land perpective: *costa brasileira; Espanha tem costa mediterrânica e costa atlântica*. From a water perspective we tend do say *margens: ligar as duas margens do Atlântico*.

Answer (score 3):

In general rivers and lakes have [*margens* (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/margem) and oceans and seas have [*costas* (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/costa). In some contexts you can also use [*beira-rio* (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/beira-rio), *beira-lago* (not in dictionaries) and [*beira-mar* (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/beira-mar). As a modifier *riverside* translates as [*ribeirinho* (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/ribeirinho) (e. g. *riverside town* = *cidade ribeirinha*).

You basically don’t say *costa do mar*, except in accidental combinations such as *costa do Mar Negro*, where *Mar* is part of the name. [*Costa* (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/costa) can mean the land near the sea, as *coast* in English, or the sea along the shore (my emphasis in all quotes):

> Da Mata Atlântica que cobria a **costa** brasileira do Rio Grande do Sul até o Ceará, só restam hoje entre 5% e 8%, na estimativa mais otimista.
>   [(*Veja*, 1997.)](https://www.google.pt/search?num=50&espv=2&biw=1242&bih=580&tbm=bks&q=%22cobria%20a%20costa%20brasileira%20do%20Rio%22&oq=%22cobria%20a%20costa%20brasileira%20do%20Rio%22&gs_l=serp.3...74363.76103.0.76537.7.7.0.0.0.0.114.659.5j2.7.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.0.0.HpP_W9LRpCA)
>
> A **costa** brasileira é rica em pescado. [(Example in Aulete 2.)](http://www.aulete.com.br/costa)

[*Margem* (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/margem) is used of both rivers and lakes. Rivers naturally have two *margens*. It may look as though a lake has a single *margem*, but the plural, *margens do lago* is idiomatic. We usually say that such and such city is located *nas margens do lago* rather than *na margem do lago*. Examples:

> **As margens do Lago Guaíba** são constituídas geralmente por praias arenosas [...]
>   [(*Revista Brazileira de Zoologia*, 2003.)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=_-dgAAAAMAAJ&q=%22as%20margens%20do%20lago%22&dq=%22as%20margens%20do%20lago%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj1sr2vj9DQAhWJ1hQKHUl4BZ4Q6AEIkQIwIQ)
>
> No dia seguinte, elas pegaram outro tour, agora para conhecer o castelo Urquhart, que fica nas **margens do Lago Ness**.
>   [(Sandra Roza, *Contos de Amor e Paixão*, 2007.)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=aVJMBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA21&dq=%22fica%20nas%20margens%20do%20lago%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjs37PrgM_QAhUHLcAKHSsqAcUQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22fica%20nas%20margens%20do%20lago%22&f=false)

[*Beira-mar* (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/beira-mar) is the area next to the sea, but to my sense it does not go as far inland as *costa* does. Similarly [*beira-rio* (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/beira-rio) is the area next to the river. These are used especially, but not only, in the phrases *à beira-mar* and *à beira-rio*. You can find *beira-lago* too, but it is not nearly as common and does not come in dictionaries. I suppose that is because in Portugal and Brazil there are a lot more things by the sea or rivers than by lakes. Examples:

> […] a **beira-rio** era uma área de lazer aos sábados.
>   [Rodrigo de Carvalhedo, *Gemeologia—O Dilema*, 2011.)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=5rDfluuOsGUC&pg=PT97&dq=%22a%20beira-rio%20era%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjdqZrImNDQAhUBMBQKHe7QC54Q6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=%22a%20beira-rio%20era%22&f=false)
>
> De Icaraí, Tatuba e Cumbuco, que ainda pertencem à região metropolitana de Fortaleza, até os confins do Estado do Piauí, **a beira-mar** é uma sequência ininterrupta de praias […]
>    [(*Guia Brasil Renault*.)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=nkeaagkpFw8C&pg=PA286&dq=%22a%20beira-mar%20%C3%A9%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjEzuDYm9DQAhVEtBQKHYXXA6AQ6AEILzAB#v=onepage&q=%22a%20beira-mar%20%C3%A9%22&f=false)
>
> […] primeira estação de veraneio dos porto-alegrenses, local onde famílias mantinham suas chácaras e moradias de verão **à beira-rio**.
>   [(Marcelo Vianna *et al* (Orgs.), *O historiador e as novas tecnologias*, 2015.)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=ChUCCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA226&dq=%22%C3%A0%20beira-rio%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjq1pPlhs_QAhXJB8AKHUzIBskQ6AEIRDAD#v=onepage&q=%22%C3%A0%20beira-rio%22&f=false)
>
> Poema **à Beira-Mar**
>   Caminhando tranquilo **à beira-mar**,
>   Pés descalços em alvos areais […]
>   [(Carlos Eduardo Drummond, *Borboleta Cor de Areia*, 2008.)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=h5xVBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA85&dq=%22%C3%A0%20beira-mar%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNopKUiM_QAhVGLMAKHZYDDYYQ6AEIiAEwDA#v=onepage&q=%22%C3%A0%20beira-mar%22&f=false)
>
> Daqui a meio século, quando a avenida **à beira-lago** estiver toda edificada […]
>   [(Afonso Arinos de Melo Franco, *A Escalada: Memórias*, 1965.)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=qL8rAAAAYAAJ&q=%22%C3%A0%20beira-lago%22&dq=%22%C3%A0%20beira-lago%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjC0Pfqic_QAhULKMAKHYHFDhMQ6AEIcTAK)

Anything along a river can be qualified as [*ribeirinho* (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/ribeirinho):

> As ilhas que se formarem em correntes comuns ou particulares pertencem aos **proprietários ribeirinhos** fronteiros, observadas as seguintes regras:
>
> I – as que se formarem no meio do rio consideram-se acréscimos sobrevindos aos **terrenos ribeirinhos** de ambas as margens […]
>   [(*Novo Código Civil Brasileiro*, 2002.)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=npdeEAHhtPkC&pg=PA57&dq=ribeirinhos&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjImM7nls_QAhXEfRoKHc6qBAcQ6AEI4AIwMQ#v=onepage&q=ribeirinhos&f=false)

In Brazil *ribeirinho* can also refer to riverside communities (e. g. *política ribeirinha*), which in some areas such as the Amazon basin appear to include pretty much everybody.